# Trying to Setup ReactJs getting error while installing web pack & bable

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

The error is as follows.  Any comments are welcome.

> npm ERR! code E404 npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/bable-preset-react - Not found npm ERR! 404
>
> npm ERR! 404  ***'bable-preset-react@latest' is not in the npm registry***.
> npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or
> use the name yourself!)
>
> npm ERR! 404
> npm ERR! 404 Note that you can
> also install from a npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git
> url.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Vamsi S
> Krishna\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-01-19T17_52_52_549Z-debug.log

Comment: there is a miss spell in you package.json or the command you are trying to run. babel is correct not bable 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react

Answer (score 0):

It should be https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-preset-react ! Babel, not Bable!